# Will socket while loop recv occur into non-completion situation?

Tags: python, sockets

This is a code snippet of socket receive data:

```
import socket
...
response = b''
temp = sock.recv(4096)
while temp:
  temp = sock.recv(4096)
  response += temp

print(response.decode(encoding="utf-8"))
```

as we know, the socket server send data to socket client, the data will stored in OS's network data cache.

then client can use `socket.recv()` to extract out.

I have a question, you see the code:

```
temp = sock.recv(4096)
while temp:
  temp = sock.recv(4096)
  response += temp
```

when send data all stored in the cache, this code I think will work fine.
but if the data is in the process of sending,
we know the while loop is very fast, will it occur into this below situation then stop recv data, so the data will not receive completely.

[image]

Comment: Speed of sending doesn't matter, `recv()` will give you whatever data it has. If it has no data it will block waiting to receive more, then give you whatever it gets when it gets there.

Comment: How recv() judge there is no data left/sending and return? `temp = socket.recv(4096)`.

Comment: The peer sending the data must provide some indication that it is finished. Usually one designs a higher-level protocol on top of the TCP stream to facilitate this, e.g. HTTP, but a simple method is for the peer to *shutdown* the write side of it's socket by calling `socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)`. This will cause recv() to return immediately with a zero-length bytes object.